# Serial communication detect

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial, communication, max232

guys.
I am workin on a project. I have two channel for Serial RS232 communication. Main and Stand-By channel. If Main channel has some problem and, cannot communicate for 15 seconds then I want to start Stand-By channel communication. How can I do that? I want to listen to channel's RX with Arduino. I think I can use MAX 232 for Serial to TTL convert. Can I listen to channel's RX with Arduino then Can I decide which channel should work?

Thank you,guys..

Comment: You could look to see if the signal is toggling. If it hasn't toggled, i.e. flatlining at logic 1 or logic 0, for more than 15 seconds, then switch to the other comms link.

Comment: If it is important to get information from one point to another, you might try a physical layer and protocol layer that is more robust than RS232.  However, if you are in the mind set of learning, the I encourage you to design in layers or robustness on top of RS232.  Such as constant pining, error detection, error correction and protection switching.

Comment: Assuming there are not large groups of data but mainly control have you looked at CAN, it is a very robust interface.